# TLS Cert for unknown IP (shippable software)

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

I am writing a distributed application that will be sold to multiple customers and hosted on premise. This application operates as a distributed system where many of the same applications communicate with each other over HTTPS as RESTful services.

Knowing I have no control over the IP address or domain name these application use I still need a default TLS certificate that ships with the app (is overridable to meet security compliance).

I can specify a wildcard name for my `CN` field in openssl as `*` but when a node tries to reach another node the cert doesn't match with the IP address it is hosted on.

Python requests library gives an error: `WARNING:urllib3.connection:Certificate did not match expected hostname: 192.168.1.150.`

- I am not asking about the above error this is just to describe my problem.

Example

HostA: `192.168.1.150:5000`

HostB: `192.168.1.151:5000`

Cert CN: `*`

`HostB -> HostA` Doesn't work because the cert doesn't specify `192.168.1.150` as an address.

Is there a proper way to handle this? I know some routers ship with default certs but they have control over their host address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly ship a default TLS certificate. What you can't do is make it not throw security warnings. It's up to the end user to replace the certs if this is an issue for them, and it's up to the developer of the product to make that as convenient as possible.

Comment: That is what I am starting to understand. I generated a wildcard cert for my lab's network and distributed the cert to each node. This works for my setup but wouldn't for someone else's. I've added a feature to allow the end user to change the cert and also a setting to override HTTPS with HTTP. Thank you!